# What is the biblical basis for 'Holy laughter'?

Tags: biblical-basis, pentecostalism, charismatic

What is the biblical basis for [Holy laughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_laughter)? Here [some examples](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22holy+laughter%22+videos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there a  biblical basis for Holy laughter?**

The short answer seems to be **yes**!

There seems to be a time for everything according to the Holy Book, at least [Ecclesiastes 3:1-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%203&version=NLT) says so:

> **A Time for Everything**
>
> 3 For everything there is a season,
> a time for every activity under heaven.
>
> 2 A time to be born and a time to die.
> A time to plant and a time to harvest.
>
> 3 A time to kill and a time to heal.
> A time to tear down and a time to build up.
>
> 4 A time to cry and a time to laugh.
> A time to grieve and a time to dance.
>
> 5 A time to scatter stones and a time to gather stones.
> A time to embrace and a time to turn away.
>
> 6 A time to search and a time to quit searching.
> A time to keep and a time to throw away.
>
> 7 A time to tear and a time to mend.
> A time to be quiet and a time to speak.
>
> 8 A time to love and a time to hate.
> A time for war and a time for peace.

Here follows 14 Bible Verses about Joy in the Old Testament:

> 1. “A merry heart doeth good like a medicine: but a broken spirit drieth the bones.” — Proverbs 17:22
> 2. “Clap your hands, all you nations; shout to God with cries of joy.” – Psaml 47:1
> 3. “God has a smile on His face.” — Psalm 42:5
> 4. “God, who sits in Heaven, laughs!” — Psalm 2:4
> 5. “He that is of a merry heart has a continual feast.” — Proverbs 15:15
> 6. “I commend mirth.” — Ecclesiastes 8:15
> 7. “I will turn their mourning into joy, I will comfort them and give them gladness for sorrow.” — Jeremiah 31:13
> 8. “Let the shield exult and everything in it. Then shall all the trees of the forest sing for joy.” — Psalm 96:12
> 9. “Let your heart be merry.” — Judges 19:6
> 10. “Make a joyful noise to the Lord, all the earth; break into joyous song and sing praises.” — Psalm 98:4
> 11. “The pastures of the wilderness overflow, the hills gird themselves wiht joy; The meadows clothe themselves with flocks, the valleys deck themselves with grain, they shout and sing together for joy.” — Psalm 65:12-13
> 12. **“Then our mouth was filled with laughter, and our tongue with shouts of joy; then it was said among the nations, the Lord has done great things for them.”** — Psalm 126:2
> 13. “You have turned my mourning into dancing; You have taken off my sackcloth and clothed me with joy.” — Psalm 30:11
> 14. “You shall go out in joy, and be led back in peace; the mountains and hills before you shall burst into song, and the trees of the field shall clap their hands.” — Isaiah 55:12